# How to show third image on lazy layout first load

Tags: javascript, html, dom, owl-carousel

I'm using Lazy layout on slider https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2

### [image]

```
  $(document).ready(function() {       
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
      items : 2,
      lazyLoad : true,
      navigation : true
    });      
  });
```

My big question is how to show 3 images on viewport that still 2 items on the slider, on my example image that slider show 2 items with full load image and third image with default/placeholder image.

Thanks in advance, I hope to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the option `lazyLoadEager` to the settings object, where the value indicates how many items to the right (and left, when loop is `true`) will be pre-loaded.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        items : 2,
        lazyLoad : true,
        lazyLoadEager:3,
        navigation : true
      });    
    });
```

More information about lazy load can be found [here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/lazyLoad.html).